# Create decorator compatible with pytest.mark.parametrize

Tags: python, pytest, decorator

I want to create a decorator for my test written with pytest. My problem, when calling decorator, pytest raises an exception that decorator hasn't got parameters "test_params".

Decorator example:

```
def decorator_example(fn):

    def create(*args, **kwargs):
        # any code here
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)

return create
```

Test example:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "test_params",
    [
        pytest.param("own_parameters")
    ])
@decorator_example
def test_1(self, fixture1, fixture2, test_params):
    pass
```

And caught exception:

```
ValueError: <function create at address> uses no argument 'test_params'
```

How can I create a decorator which will be compatible with pytest's parametrized test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `decorator_example` replaces the `test_1` function with the wrapper function `create` that has a completely different signature, breaking `pytest` introspection (e.g. checking whether `create` has an argument `test_params` fails because there are only `*args` and `**kwargs` available). You need to use [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) to mimic the wrapped function's signature:

```
import functools


def decorator_example(fn):

    @functools.wraps(fn)    
    def create(*args, **kwargs):
        # any code here
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)

    return create
```

#### Python 2.7 compatibility

You can make use of the [`decorator`](https://pypi.org/project/decorator/) package. Install it with the usual

```
$ pip install decorator
```

The above example will be:

```
import decorator


def decorator_example(fn):
    def create(fn, *args, **kwargs):
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorator.decorator(create, fn)
```

Or using [`six`](https://pypi.org/project/six/):

```
import six


def decorator_example(fn):

    @six.wraps(fn)    
    def create(*args, **kwargs):
        # any code here
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)

    return create
```

Comment: sorry, but it doesnt work. Now, when i call wrapped method then "create" function called as test_1, and error become 
`ValueError: <function test_1 at address> uses no argument 'test_params'`

Comment: Note: i use python 2.7

Comment: No worries - this is what the accept button is for. I have tried the code you provided in the question and it works. Can you update the code in question with the failing example?

Comment: Ah, I see - `functools.wraps` will not suffice in case of Python 2.7; use `decorator` package. Let me update the answer with an example.

Comment: I have added an example using `decorator`, check it out.

Comment: I have the same code as in the question and use python 2.7.16. Right now i found at github a thread where described that `@functools.wraps` have bug in python 2 version and insted of this we must use fixed version of this function from six library. Then your answer is correct but for version python 2 correct decorator `@six.wraps`

Comment: Ah, sure, `six` will also do the trick; will add an example for it too.

Comment: I believe that your decision right, but on my project better to use six library instead of use new dependency. Thank you for replies and patient

Comment: Sure, the solution using `six` is perfectly valid and I'd also prefer it (although completely forgotten about that lib). Glad I could help!